# Object does not exists at location at android firebase upload file

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to create an app using firebase storage service. I have a function that saves an image from device local storage, uses the URI of the picture to save it to firebase. When trying to upload the image to firebase server I get "object does not exist at location", probaby meaning there is a problem which my URI.

I am adding the entire activity so you can see what is going on -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final int DELAY_MILLIS = 5000;

    private Button buttonChooseImage, buttonUpload;
    private TextView textViewShowUpload;
    private EditText editTextFileName;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private Uri imageUri;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonChooseImage = findViewById(R.id.button_choose_image);
        buttonUpload = findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
        textViewShowUpload = findViewById(R.id.text_view_show_uploads);
        editTextFileName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_file_name);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        buttonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewShowUpload.setOnClickListener(this);

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_choose_image:
                openFileChooser();
                break;
            case R.id.button_upload:
                uploadFile();
                break;
            case R.id.text_view_show_uploads:

                break;
        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mine = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mine.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadFile() {
        if (imageUri != null) {
            StorageReference fileRefrence = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));
            fileRefrence.putFile(imageUri).
                    addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    progressBar.setProgress(0);
                                }
                            }, DELAY_MILLIS);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Upload upload = new Upload(editTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                    taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                            String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                            databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No File Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(imageView);

        }
    }
}
```

Am I implementing URI incorrectly?

edit -

tryed this solution from comments, yet still getting the same error -

```
private void uploadFile() {
        if (imageUri != null) {
            StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child("images/" + imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            UploadTask uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imageUri);
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(0);
                        }
                    }, DELAY_MILLIS);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Upload upload = new Upload(editTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                            taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                    String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                    databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                    progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                }
            });



        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No File Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: is the image getting displayed in the imageView `Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(imageView);`, also is `getFileExtension` giving u the correct extension?

Comment: about the imageview - yes, it is being displayed. about the getFileExtension - it seems like it does not print to log anything, I have tried in my uploadFile method to print to the log both fileRefrence.getPath() and fileRefrence.getName() and nothing appears.

Comment: Is your file uploaded successfully on firebase storage and you are able to update the firebase realtime database afterwards ?

Comment: nope. nothing is being added onto firebase storage and obviously I can't edit nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me Uploading was possible with this code. I got this at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPfQN-Sfnjw&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuBf5KH4XXOthtgo6E4Epjl8&index=4 in the comment section. Also set the authentication in your firebase storage to true

```
private void uploadFile(){
    if(mImageUri!=null){
            storageReference.putFile(mImageUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>()
            {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception
                {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return storageReference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task)
                {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        Log.e("TAG", "then: " + downloadUri.toString());


                        Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                downloadUri.toString());
                        databaseReference.push().setValue(upload);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "upload failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please upload image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
StorageReference imageReference = storageReference.child("uploads");  

              UploadTask uploadTask = imageReference.putFile(imageuri);
                    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(verify.this, "Upload failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            if (taskSnapshot.getMetadata() != null) {
                                if (taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference() != null) {

                                    Task<Uri> result = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                                    result.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
```

Comment: Remember to close the required bracket where it needed!!

Comment: I am a little confused as to where should this code go or what should it replace. Could you be please more specific about that?

Comment: ok! you copy the code from StorageReference to ** DELAY_MILLIS** and after that add a string to convert Uri to string...Basically, it would be **String imagepath=uri.toString* * ,where uri is the Uri of image which get upload

Comment: I am still having difficulities understanding you - what exactly should I replace in what?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code:

```
            StorageReference fileRefrence = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));
```

with this:

```
            StorageReference fileRefrence = storageReference.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Comment: still gives me the object does not exist at path error. Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: it should be `imageUri.getLastPathSegment());`, I had `uri.getLastPathSegment()`

Comment: Does not work. tried that - please check my edit at the main post to see what I have already tried, if you may be able to offer some solution that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code what i have used for my project and its working...
Also make sure that

- you have make rules public on firebase storage
- added the permission in your manifest file for access phone storage and internet
- added all required dependencies for firebase storage access

StorageReference storageReference;
storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

StorageReference refStorage = storageReference.child("images/"+uri.getLastPathSegment());
   UploadTask uploadTask = refStorage.putFile(uri);

```
Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new Exception("task is not succeeded");
        } return refStorage.getDownloadUrl();
    }//end of throws Exception method
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            downUri = task.getResult();
        } else {
            // Handle failures
            // ...
            Log.d("<<<<<<<<", "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< not uplooaded ");
        }
    }//end of onComplete()for getting download uri
});
```

Comment: you copied something from your project that does not fit correctly to mine. Could you please explain at what part do I need to put this block of code, according to my MainActivity?

Comment: change your this code--->   StorageReference fileRefrence = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));
            fileRefrence.putFile(imageUri).    with this--->                                           StorageReference refStorage = storageReference.child("images/"+uri.getLastPathSegment()); UploadTask uploadTask = refStorage.putFile(uri);                                                 and then add onSuccessfullListeners. Try this code, it may help you

Comment: I have edited the main post with your solution so you can see what I have done according to what you suggested - yet nothing changed. The same error is still being presented.

Comment: can you show me error log, so that i can understand the error causing your application.